# Why must I dbclick to trigger an effect of toggling class in IE while click only once in ie or chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser

As you see 
[image: This is not a input tag, but an <i> tag]
Below is my html-

```
<a id="notice" href="javascript:void(0)" class="checkBox">
    <i class="icon i2_18"></i>
    <input id="cbxNotice" type="hidden" value="0" name="cbxNotice">
</a>
```

and this is my jquery

```
$("#notice").click(function () {
    if ($("#cbxNotice").val() == "1") {
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("tick").addClass("empty");
        $("#cbxNotice").val("0");
    } else {
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("empty").addClass("tick");
        $("#cbxNotice").val("1");
    }
});
```

In Chrome and Firefox, I just click once to trigger the effect(from empty to tick)
but in IE, why do I need to double-click to trigger the effect?

THANKS!!

Comment: Your input tag should not be inside of an anchor tag, in this case you can just use a div and your issue will probably disappear

Comment: Sorry, My title is this - Why must I dbclick to trigger an effect of toggling class in IE while click only once in firefox or chrome?

Comment: Thanks, but as you see, there is nothing to do with my hidden input tag, which is just created for transfer values. The checkbox-like image is <i> tag with different class name, and the class has different images settings.

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle maybe

Comment: which IE version did you have to double click?

Comment: Could have something to do with the href js void thing but I have to test it out

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mxCBD/1/ I checked on IE 11 and it seems fine, I don't have IE 10. You can check it on your IE and let us know if you get the same thing